# Transform a factor into a matrix of 2 columns in R

Tags: categorical-data, matrix

I have a column of continuous values that goes from 0 to 21600 approximately.

I am trying to get this data binned in ranges of 100 and get the frequencies of them, e.g:
[0,100) - 35, [100,200) - 57, and so on.

What I am doing is this:

binned <- cut(x, breaks = c(0, seq(100, 21600, by = 100)))

And I get the data in ranges, e.g (7.5e+03,7.6e+03]   (1.8e+03,1.9e+03]   (1e+03,1.1e+03]     (1.1e+03,1.2e+03]   (100,200] ... and so on

What I want now is to get a matrix of two columns, the first one with the categories (the ranges like [0, 100), [100,200) and the second one with its frequency

Can anyone help me? This may be trivial but I am a newbe in R :(

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. But first, what you want is a data.frame (or even better a data.table or a tbl) since you are now dealing with things of different types. The counts are numbers and the ranges are factors.

To count easily, use `table` and from there put it into a data.frame

```
count_bins <- table(binned)
catfreq <- data.frame(count_bins)
```

Alternatively, you can replace `data.frame` with `data.table` which I prefer for a variety of reasons.